# How to rewrite 2 GET parameters using mod_rewrite in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Need rewrite from old URL:

```
example.com/search?search_query=SOMEQUERY&search_type=videos&type=public
```

to

```
example.com/search/videos?search_query=SOMEQUERY&type=public
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like the following near the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search_query=([^&]*)&search_type=(videos)&type=(public)$
RewriteRule ^search$ /search/%2?search_query=%1&type=%3 [R,L]
```

This is an exact match for the example URL given, except that *SOMEQUERY* is variable.

`%1`, `%2` and `%3` are backreferences to the corresponding captured subpatterns in the preceding *CondPattern*. ie. `<SOMEQUERY>`, `videos` and `public`. `%2` and `%3` are really just for consistency and to allow you to easily add another *search_type* for instance. eg. `search_type=(videos|images)`.

This is a temporary (302) redirect. Change the `R` to `R=301` if this is intended to be permanent, but only after you have ensured it's working OK. (301s are cached hard by the browser so can make testing problematic.)

Comment: Works great! Thank you so much! Very intelligibly and clearly explained.
There is one more small problem with the encoding of the Cyrillic alphabet in the query. We will solve this with php or nginx. All the best to you!